# Having a DIV to the right of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Note: I use Bootsrap and jQuery

Because Forms will submit the first [button type=submit] that is listed when Enter is pressed on a input control, I need to list in html one of my buttons before the other, however, visually they need to appear in reverse.

so i need them listed in the HTML like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="glyphicon-chevron-right"></button>
<button type="submit" class="glyphicon-chevron-left"></button>
```

but they need to render so that the right arrow one is visually on the right of the left arrow one.

How do I make the right arrow control render to the right of the left arrow control?

Comment: You will have to position them with CSS.

Comment: float the element in CSS... not javascript related at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will probably go for this (depending on how you want to display the buttons relatively to the container):

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <button type="submit" class="glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></button>
    <button type="submit" class="glyphicon-chevron-left"></button>
</div>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CHeb3/

Answer (score 1):

You could use absolute positioning to achieve this:

CSS:

```
.container {position:relative}
.glyphicon-chevron-left, .glyphicon-chevron-right {position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
.glyphicon-chevron-right {left:30px}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <button type="submit" class="glyphicon-chevron-right"></button>
    <button type="submit" class="glyphicon-chevron-left"></button>  
</div>
```

Just change the left/top values to where you need them positioned